# Override anchor tag clicks and update in dynamically rendered html in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-typescript

I am making an api call in react to fetch html and bind to the inner html of a div in react.
The issue I am currently facing is that dynamically rendered html has links that I want to override on click and update the state in react.

How do I go about it?

Below is code on the work I have done so far.

```
export const HtmlReportViewer:React.FC<HtmlReportViewerProps> = (props) => {
    const {reportPath, reportParams} = props;
    const htmlStringRef = React.useRef();
    const [htmlString, setHtmlString] = React.useState('<p>Hello</p>')

    const getReportAsHtml = async () => {
        const payload = {
            ReportPath: reportPath,
            JsonParameters: JSON.stringify(paramsToArray(reportParams)),
            RenderAs: "HTML4.0"
        }
        const rawResponse = await fetch('api/ReportServer/GetHtml', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Options': JSON.stringify(payload),
            },
          });
          return await rawResponse.text();
    }
    React.useEffect(() => {
      // make call to set report html string to report
      getReportAsHtml().then((data) => {
        setHtmlString(data);
    
      })
    })

    return (
        <div ref={htmlStringRef} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlString}}>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-sky-ymt0ft?file=/src/App.js)

First of all, your `useEffect` should have a dependency array, because now it will run every render

```
useEffect(() => {
  getReportAsHtml().then((data) => {
    setHtmlString(data);
  });
}, []);
```

You can't use react's API to capture events, because you insert HTML directly, so you have to add listeners yourself.

I would use

- `MutationObserver` to detect changes to your div
- `querySelectorAll` to get the `a` tags
- `addEventListener` to add the listeners

```
useEffect(() => {
  // your onclick function
  const handler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do whatever you want
  };

  // your observer
  const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
    // this will run every time the HTML in the div changes
    // get the elements
    const elements = htmlStringRef.current.querySelectorAll("a");
    // assign click listener
    elements.forEach((anchor) => anchor.addEventListener("click", handler));
  });

  // observe
  observer.observe(htmlStringRef.current, { childList: true });
}, []);
```

It should work just like this, but not removing the listeners will cause bugs

```
useEffect(() => {
  // array for elements
  let elements = [];

  const handler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do whatever you want
  };

  // function for clearing the listeners
  const clearListeners = () =>
    elements.forEach((el) => el.removeEventListener("click", handler));

  const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
    // before getting new elements, clear old listeners
    clearListeners();
    elements = htmlStringRef.current.querySelectorAll("a");
    elements.forEach((anchor) => anchor.addEventListener("click", handler));
  });

  observer.observe(htmlStringRef.current, { childList: true });

  // remember to remove everything when component is unmounted
  return () => {
    clearListeners();
    observer.disconnect();
  };
}, []);
```

Full code

```
import { useEffect, useReducer, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const htmlStringRef = useRef(null);
  const [htmlString, setHtmlString] = useState();
  const [clicks, addClicks] = useReducer((state) => state + 1, 0);

  const getReportAsHtml = async () => {
    return '<p>some text with a <a href="#">link</a></p>';
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let elements = [];

    const handler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      addClicks();
    };

    const clearListeners = () =>
      elements.forEach((el) => el.removeEventListener("click", handler));

    const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
      clearListeners();
      elements = htmlStringRef.current.querySelectorAll("a");
      elements.forEach((anchor) => anchor.addEventListener("click", handler));
    });

    observer.observe(htmlStringRef.current, { childList: true });

    return () => {
      clearListeners();
      observer.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getReportAsHtml().then((data) => {
      setHtmlString(data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        ref={htmlStringRef}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString }}
      ></div>
      {clicks}
    </>
  );
}
```